Why doesn't "smooth" scrollIntoView work on Safari?
I have a React18 app with a seemingly simple problem:
The scrollIntoView method is causing jumping from the top to the bottom of the page as it renders in Safari.
Other browsers including edge and chrome work properly.
I tried a few approaches that didn't work. It seems the best option for now is to simply turn the behavior to "auto" on Safari and "smooth" on others.
The MDN docs say, "Before Safari 15.4, there was no support for the smooth behavior."
But it should be supported (I'm on Safari 17.1).
--
video of problem (48 sec)
I'm defining the ref and the scroll effect here:
const chatMessageRef = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null);
  useEffect(() => {
    if (chatMessageRef.current) {
      chatMessageRef.current.scrollIntoView({
        // behavior: 'smooth',
        behavior: isSafari() ? 'auto' : 'smooth', // TODO: get smooth scroll to work on Safari
      });
    }
  }, [chatMessages]);

And here I map over the messages and assign the ref to the last chatMessage in the array:
      <section id="chats" className="grow flex flex-col overflow-y-auto pl-3 pr-5 pt-3 pb-3">
        {chatMessages.map((chat, index) => (
          <ChatMessage
            key={index}
            created={chat.created}
            role={chat.role}
            message={chat.message}
            isTyping={index === chatMessages.length - 1 && isTyping}
            ref={index === chatMessages.length - 1 ? chatMessageRef : null}
          />
        ))}
      </section>

Any help is greatly appreciated!
